# After delete controller, laravel throwing BindingResolutionException error (laravel 7)

Tags: binding, controller, laravel-7

this my issue..

> I added app/Http/Controllers/OrdersController.php

at the same time inside web.php got such

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['adminlogin']], function () {
    Route::match(['get','post'],'/admin/add-order','OrdersController@addOrder');
    Route::match(['get','post'],'/admin/edit-order/{id}','OrdersController@editOrder');
});
```

Everything was works fine.

However, After I copy whole folder to a new computer and then deleted the physical file OrdersController.php, system throw error below:

> ```
> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController] does not exist
> ```

```
Then I go to comment out all the path in web.php with OrdersController, 
and run 

 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan view:clear
 php artisan route:clear
 php artisan config:clear
```

System still throw the same error.

Apparently the system trying to detect and find OrdersController.php

What more I need to do properly clean it after I physically deleted a Controller file?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what you have inside your route at the first place

```
php artisan route:list
```

then run

```
php artisan optimize
```

see if that works...

Comment: I faced the same issue and this solution worked for me. Thanks a lot.